# Why is the Team button on Dota 2 unclickable?

Tags: dota-2

I have a team but the Team button on the profile seems grayed out and cannot be clicked but when I checked my teammate's profile I can click the Team button and I can see myself there.

Comment: Have you tried logging out and then logging back in? Such glitches are usually one time glitches and that next time you log in, it should be okay

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under *Community>My teams* there is an option **Show this team on your player profile** selecting it will make that team button on your profile clickable.

However it is a bit **bugged**,so sometimes game will just forget your selection and put back that grayed icon.

Answer (score 2):

There are several explanations:

1. Random Glitch : rebooting steam could do the trick
2. The last update disabled team menu
3. There are some issue with dota2 network and you should be able to access it soon (The same problem occurs sometime with inventories)
4. You are too good/bad to have a team (just kidding)

Comment: Hahaha I love 4th explanation :))